# Yii createCommand Update with bindValue

Tags: php, database, yii, bindvalue

I'm using createCommand in Yii Framework and I want to know about use bindValue for the params, Ex:

```
Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
                            ->update('table', array(
                            'field'=>'$valuefield',
                            ), 'id_table=:id_table', array(':id_table'=>$id_table));
```

In this case, the value of $valuefield and $id_table are protected? Or I should create the sql query manually and pass the parameters with bindValue?

Thank you!

Comment: what do you mean for `are protected`?

Comment: If by _protected_ you mean _escaped_, then `$id_table` is escaped because you're passing it correctly. `$valuefield` will not be passed correctly, because you have it in single quotes. Do it this way: `Yii::app()->db->createCommand()->update('table', array('field'=>':valuefield'), 'id_table=:id_table', array(':id_table'=>$id_table, ':valuefield'=>$valuefield));`

Comment: I wanted mean sanitized. Thank you for your reply, i will apply it in my query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In this case, the value of $valuefield and $id_table are protected?

Yes. Method `update` automaticly binds array's values passed in second param. And also you manualy bind param for condition. To prevent SQL injection always use binding.

Comment: Perfect! What the best way for I manualy bind param for condition in update command?